# 07 Camry Engine slow RPM and excessive fuel consumption reading

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-consumption, camry, fuel-injectors

I have 2007 Camry manual made in Australia for Arabic gulf. The engine sometimes go to 500 rpm and suddenly stops. Or it also goes to 1500 rpm and doesn't return to 1000 rpm (which is the normal as far as I know). Also the fuel consumption calculator gives 13L/100Km which very high compared to 9L/100Km that I used to know.

I cleaned the air intake where the paddle control the air vent space. I also added injection cleaner to the fuel tank. I did that once and it worked.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is very broad because so many things could be causing this. When was the last time the car had a complete service? Is the Check Engine light on? Have you had the codes read? Without more information, there isn't much we can help you with.

Comment: @CharlieRB, Thank you. It is embarrassing that I am in Africa, we don't have complete service for cars except the agent-which cost huge amount of money. The Check Engine light is OFF, I didn't make a code reads, but I can do in a day.

Comment: Its the throttle position sensor. Get it scanned. And clean the throttle body butterfly valve on both sides.

Comment: @NumairAidroos, I had already cleaned the throttle body butterfly (I named it air intake paddle-I am a newbie). It was dirty,some black viscus material was there. I will scan this sensor.

Comment: I know it is not a selling website, but if I get any code reader I could do this?(Cheap ones ~35$) I don't have one but I will buy one.

Comment: I think any decent OBDII code reader should work - we can't advise which one to get as we don't know what is available in your country

Comment: @NickC, I found Autel MaxiScan MS509, available.

Comment: Looking at the specs online, I think that should work fine

Comment: @NickC, I will get it and find what does it read. But it took 2 days.

Comment: @NumairAidroos When I do the code reading, if the throttle position sensor give an error, what I have to do? does it need a cleaning or replacing?

Comment: Replace it. And you'll need to get the ECU to sync. Get this done at Toyota.

Comment: @NumairAidroos, I will do it if the code give me an error. 
I cleaned the butterfly with spray, the r.p.m now seems to be OK, but the fuel consumption calculator still give excessive consumption (~12L/100Km). Does the throttle position sensor could effect the calculations without being a real fuel consumption?

Comment: No, it should not.